# Why does my sql select not work?

Tags: c#, sql

I keep getting this exception:

> No data exists for the row/column.

Yet the info in the select is correct. I don't know why this keeps failing.

```
 string SQL = "SELECT htmlCodeBlock FROM HTML WHERE htmlID = 1";
 command.CommandText = SQL;
 command.Connection = conn;
 reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 codeBlock = reader["htmlCodeBlock"].ToString();
 reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you call `Read()` on the DataReader before trying to read data from it.

[Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something!

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any reading on using data readers?  It would appear not.  You have to call `Read` before actually reading the data of a row.  You call `Read` once to get to the first row.  You call `Read` a second time to get to the second row. Etc.

Also, if your intention is to retrieve a single value then you should probably be calling `ExecuteScalar` instead, which actually returns a single value.  Just be aware that it will return `null` (as opposed to `DBNull.Value`) if there is no value to retrieve.